# How to sort float values?

Tags: sorting, unix, floating-point

I want to sort a big ascii file. Example:

```
-10
+9.9
-1.003
-6
4.01
```

`sort -n` gives:

```
-1.003         # -1.003 is bigger than -10
-10            #
-6
+9.9
4.01
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-g` instead of `-n`:

```
sort -g file
```

It returns:

```
-10
-6
-1.003
4.01
+9.9
```

From `man sort`:

```
   -g, --general-numeric-sort
          compare according to general numerical value
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem seems to be the + charachter ...
maybe you can just filter the + charachter like this:

```
less yourfile | tr -d '+' | sort -n
```

Comment: I removed the "+"  sign. But I still have the same result.